# Jslint and sublime text

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2

I'm working with Sublime Text 2 for writing my javascript codes, and I want to know if there is anyway to indent the codes and make them in order after writing.

Every time I use tab and space and it's hard for me to keep them inline.

Is JSLint related to what I need?

Should I add any extra feature to Sublime Text?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Select all text -> Edit -> Line -> Reindent